# Cassandra: execute vs. executeAsync

Tags: java, asynchronous, cassandra, datastax, execute

I do not understand the `executeAsync()`-method of `Session`-Interface in package `com.datastax.driver.core` of Java Cassandra-Driver. 
Ok you can send your query and proceed with the main code, but to get the result you have the invoke `get()`-method from `ResultFuture` , which is again blocking.

Would it not be more reasonable, to invoke `execute()`-method in a background thread?

Comment: You don't have to call `get` in a blocking manner. The method returns a `ResultSetFuture` which is a `ListenableFuture`, on which you can `addListener`.

Comment: See examples in the [official tutorial](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/java-driver-async-queries).